# Hovering Issue With Nav Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

My mega menu nav has a hovering issue. It activates when hovering over invisible child list items (mousing over from bottom to top, you'll notice the issue on [this codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/EBrodo?editors=1111a)).

This is the block of CSS that's triggering the hover:

```
.nav:hover > li > .subnav-block {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

I'm thinking a JavaScript solution would help out but trying to find CSS fix for this first.

Comment: `visibility: hidden;` means the element takes up space and reacts to the mouse, it's just not drawn to the screen. Use `display: none` instead, or `height: 0`. (I've also removed the React tag, given that it has no relevance to the issue here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sub-navigation menu is taking up space, even though it is not visible. That is why you can see it whenever you are hovering above it. Adding `height:0` to your `.subnav-block` and then setting it back to `auto` when hovering, should do the trick. Your css should look something like the one below.

```
.subnav-block {
  position: static;
  display: block;
  width: 100% !important;
  top: 54px;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
}

.nav:hover > li > .subnav-block {
  height: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to add paddings to your sub-navigation menu, setting the `height` to 0 won't suffice, and you would need to change both the `height` and the `padding` when hovering. There is another way, which **Hadi77** mentioned, which is setting the default display to `none` and then change it to `block`. Just like the example below.

```
.subnav-block {
  position: static;
  width: 100% !important;
  top: 54px;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
}

.nav:hover > li > .subnav-block {
  display: block;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Since `display` won't let us use transitions, the other workaround would be using a bit of `JS`. Since it is not much code, it is solid way to achieve this. We would need to remove the CSS `hover` in this.

**JS**

```
const nav = document.querySelectorAll('.nav > li');

nav.forEach(elem => {

  elem.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    const subnav = document.querySelectorAll('.subnav-block');
    subnav.forEach(sub => {
      sub.classList.add('display-block');
      setTimeout( () => { 
        sub.style.opacity = 1;
        sub.style.height = 'auto';
      }, 100);
    });
  });

  elem.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    const subnav = document.querySelectorAll('.subnav-block');
    subnav.forEach(sub => {
      sub.classList.remove('display-block');
      sub.style.opacity = 0;
    });
  });

});
```

**CSS**

```
.subnav-block {
  position: static;
  width: 100% !important;
  top: 54px;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
}

.display-block {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to add padding to '.subnav-block', that also takes up space and we run into a similar issue. How can I make the subnav look good w/o sacrificing the hover experience?

Comment: I would then go with Hadi77 answer and instead use the display attribute. I just edited my question with the corresponding changes.

Comment: yeah, I was just playing around with display none instead of visibility hidden. Thanks, will continue.

Comment: Maybe I need to pose another topic on this but noticed the animation doesn't work when using display:none and display:block. How do I get CSS transition to work again?

Comment: You would need to use a bit of JS in this case. I just edited my answer with a simple code that should suffice.

Comment: That's awesome. last question (I think): when submenu is visible, it pushes content down. I'm assuming it's b/c it is block displayed. Should I use position absolute to fix this?

Comment: Yes, using position absolute should fix that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196339/discussion-between-eric-nguyen-and-alain-cruz).

Answer (score 1):

Setting `visibility` to `hidden`, is somewhat like making it transparent: The element takes space as it should (`display` is set to `block`).

Using `display` property is what you want. Set it to `none` when you want the element to be "not displayed" and set it to `block` to "display it".

---

Also if you don't want all menus to drop-down together, move the `:hover` pseudo-selector in `.nav:hover > li > .subnav-block` to `li`, so it would become `.nav > li:hover > .subnav-block`.